# Max output voltage microphone

Tags: microphone

Do you know what's the max output volatge can perform a microphone with this Specifications?

Type: Microphone

Cable length: 100cm / 3.28ft

Sensitivity: -43±1dB

Directivity: Uni-Directional

Output Impedance: ≤680Ω

Operation Voltage: DC1.0V - 10V

Current Consumption: < 0.5mA

Signal to Noise Ratio:≥ 56dB

Frequency Range: 50-16,000Hz

Answer (score 2):

It obviously depends on the sound recorded but you can expect it somewhere in the region between 1mV to a few tens of mV according to [Shure](http://www.shure.com/americas/support/find-an-answer/mic-level-and-line-level-what-do-they-mean).